# What files do I need in my home to login in to unity?

Tags: unity, login, files, home-directory

I have replaced the generated home with my old home folder. Now I can not log in to unity. (i can login to tty1)

How do I best fix this?

What files is needed in home to login?

I started without:
 .xsession file.

Comment: Do you have a .xsession file in your home? Rename or delete it and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very bizarre situation you have their. My best advice to this would create a new user from TTY1 (terminal) using the command `adduser`.

```
sudo adduser newuser
```

If you are able to login with the newuser account, then just copy the files out of /home/newuser into your home folder. Also, if you have to copy the files as root, make sure you correct the file ownerships.

```
sudo cp -a /home/newuser/. /home/myname/
sudo chown -R myname:myname /home/myname
```

Comment: This solves the problem but do not answer the question. This solution resets settings in the old home that perhaps is unnecessary if a user knows what files actually is required.